# Twitting same body at the time

Tags: twitter

I got problem twitting same body at the same time by using Twitter API, I would like to know when can i post it again using either Twitter API  or directly twit on twitter.

Example.

I twitted body = Good Morning! #goodmorning 5mins ago

I twtted body = Good Morning! #goodmorning

Error Code 403, twitter response you're already twitted this.

Hope you help here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't post the same tweet twice to twitter see [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3714) and [this](http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-tips/should-you-ever-repeat-the-same-tweets/)

you need to change the tweet somehow to avoid spam detection.